# Can I use a "be" not after a modal verb or "to"?

Tags: grammaticality

I always think "be" should be after "would, should, could ..." and "to".
But I see this today.

> Any test which **be** migrated without this tool, will be charged as per
>   Azure pricing.

Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: No: and you don't need "which" either. Just say: _Any test migrated without this tool will be charged as per Azure pricing_. Note that a comma after "tool" is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [1] *Any test* [*which is migrated without this tool*] *will be charged as per*
>   *Azure pricing*.
>
> [2] *Any test* [*migrated without this tool*] *will be charged as per*
>   *Azure pricing*.

No: you cannot use the plain form "be".

Either use "which is" in a relative clause as in [1], or a past-participial clause, as in [2].

Note also that you must not insert a comma after "tool". Punctuation should not be used to separate subject and verb.